# How can I change the browser value from properties file using command line to run the selenium test case

Tags: java, linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cmd

I want to run test case on multiple browser, for that i want to change the browser value from properties value. But i don't want to change it manually. Can i update the value using cmd or using any other option?

Comment: Your code trials please.

Answer (score 0):

1) pass in the brower in command line like  `-Dbrowser=Chrome`

2) get the command parameter value in Java code like 
`String browser = System.getProperty("browser", "Chrome")`  
// the second argument is defautl value when you not use `-Dbrowser=xxx` in commmand line

Answer (score 0):

Convert your script to testng. You can specify the browser value in the testng.xml file.You can specify the browser in :

```
<parameter name="browser" value="Firefox"/>
```

and on your testcase pass the value the browser as :

```
@Parameters({ "browser" })

@BeforeTest

public void beforetest(String browser) throws Exception
{
    try {
        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox")) {
            System.out.println(browser);
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","path_to\\geckodriver.exe");;
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            System.out.println(browser);
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","path_to\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("IE")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "path_to\\IEDriverServer.exe");
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        }
    } catch (WebDriverException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Here is a sample testng.xml file

```
 <suite name="Suite"  thread-count="2" parallel="true">
  <test name="Test1">
    <parameter name="browser" value="Firefox"/>
      <classes>
        <class name="stackoverflow.parallel"/>
      </classes>
  </test> 
  <test name="Test2">
   <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
    <classes>
       <class name="stackoverflow.parallel"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```